# jqplot Can't hide x axis

Tags: jqplot

I need to hide the x axis info for some line plots.
I've tried various options including:

```
{
  axes: {
    xaxis: {
      show: false
    }
  }
}

{
  axesDefaults: {
    show: false
  }
  axes: {
    xaxis: {
      show: false
    }
    yaxis: {
      show: true
    }
  }
}
```

But it seems that no matter what I do the x axis is shown.
Am I using the wrong option?  or using the right option incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was provided with a correct answer by Larry, a user on the Google groups jqplot forum:

```
       options: {      
           axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    tickOptions: {
                        show: false
                    },
                    rendererOptions: {
                        drawBaseline: false
```